# For mapStateToProps not matching props in test file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux

What changes I have to do with mapStateToProps so passing props to unit test file should not show error

Tsx file contains

```
export type props = {
  productionStatusTrendBarData: IProductionStatusResponse[],
  durationType: string,
  productionStatusTrendShift: shiftDetails[]
}
    const ProductionsTrendChart = ({ productionStatusTrendBarData, durationType, productionStatusTrendShift }: props) => {
    return(...)}
    const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
      productionStatusTrendBarData: state.productionStatusReducer.productionStatusTrendData.plStatusChartBars,
      productionStatusTrendShift: state.productionStatusReducer.productionStatusTrendData.plDayShiftDetails,
      durationType: state.kpiMetrics.durationType,
    })
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductionsTrendChart);
```

I am trying to write test cases for this component

```
<ContentWrapper>
       <ProductionsTrendChart {...propsShift} />
</ContentWrapper>,);
```

Below error shown while passing props

> Type '{ productionStatusTrendBarData: { filterApplied: string; targetUnits: number; completedUnits: number; capacityUnits: number; gapOrExcess: number; }[]; durationType: string; productionStatusTrendShift: never[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { context?: Context<ReactReduxContextValue<any, AnyAction>> | undefined; store?: Store<...> | undefined; }'.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, your code is not completed